# Generate (dynamically) a table with X amount rows and Y amount columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Any idea on a different way to implement a code to generate a (dynamically) a table with X amount rows and Y amount columns as the reference one below?

```
function makeGrid(x, y) {
  for (var line = 1; line <= y; line++) {
    $('#pixelCanvas').append('<tr id=table' + line + '></tr>');
    for (var column = 1; column <= x; column++) {
      $('#table' + line).append('<td></td>');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Does it work? Are there errors? It's very readable at the moment.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to help us help you.

Comment: You'll want to tag jQuery also, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this anwser is the one !

> Note : You can remove the styling classes inside the function to keep it as you wish !! mine was just for clarification.

```js
const Generate = (x, y) => {
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  // table.className = "table table-tp-1";
  let thead_elements = "";
  let tbody_elements = "";
  let tbody_elements_td = "";
  for (let column = 0; column < y; column++) {
    thead_elements += `<th> col ${column + 1}</th>`;
    tbody_elements_td += `<td> data ${column + 1}</td>`;
  }
  for (let row = 0; row < x; row++) {
    tbody_elements += "<tr>" + tbody_elements_td + "</tr>";
  }
  // Create Tbody Elements
  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");

  thead.classList = "marineblue-bg white ";
  thead.innerHTML = thead_elements;
  tbody.innerHTML = tbody_elements;
  //Append Elements
  table.appendChild(thead);
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  document.querySelector(".table").appendChild(table);
};

Generate(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://lionzcss-api.herokuapp.com/api/css/lionzcss"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="table table-tp-1"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```